# How to force selection in React Select?

Tags: reactjs

I have a select list (from react-select library).
How to force the first item of the **seasons** array to be selected by default and how to carry out the **renderMatches function** depending on that automatic choice?
My not-working solution:

```
<Select
  onChange = {(e) => renderMatches(e)}
  value = {seasons[0]}
  options = {seasons}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

is `<Select />` a component that you have created?

if **Yes** I will need some more info to answer your question, if **No** are you using a library? which one?

On the other hand, you should probably have a `selected` state or something that goes into `value={selected}` and you can set the default value of it in the `componentDidMount` or in `useEffect` hook.

Comment: yes that's a react-select library

Comment: Just took a look at the docs, I think if you do what I said above your problem will go away.
setting a **static** `value` is probably what is messing up with your code

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `defaultValue` prop for the react-select component, that fixes the default value on render. Here is an example of that:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ryvdpq

After that, the value will be set to whatever you set the value prop to. I might be missing something else, but from the code I can't really tell what you are trying to accomplish with the `renderMatches` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by converting the first value of array as

```
let seasonValue = {
  value: seasons[0].YourValue,
  label: seasons[0].YourLabel,
};
this.setState({ value: seasonValue });
```

and you can use can use this value

```
<Select
onChange = {(e) => renderMatches(e)}
value = {value}
options = {seasons} 
/>
```

or check the documentation [here](https://react-select.com/home)